# How do I convert RSA-key integers into useable/PKCS format?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I've managed to generate my own prime numbers, p and q, and the other relevant RSA values, n, e, and d. These are all just integers... I have not been able to find any method to convert/encode them to the commonly used format that has the BEGIN PRIVATE KEY or BEGIN PUBLIC KEY at the top. Is there a way I can do this in python to achieve that common key format?

Comment: Artjom, I have pycrypto but have not found any guides that show how to use it for that purpose.

Comment: As far as I can tell, rsa.exportKey requires the key already be in one of the encoded formats. That is what I am struggling with. I can't figure out how to properly encode/convert the long-int which most of these numbers are.

Answer (score 4):

> I've managed to generate my own prime numbers, p and q, and the other relevant RSA values, n, e, and d.

Then you can create a pyCrypto key object that holds this information:

```
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> privateKey = RSA.construct((n, e, d))
>>> publicKey = RSA.construct((n, e))
```

After that you can export the keys to a textual representation (PEM) in PKCS#1 format:

```
>>> privateKey.exportKey()
'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMI....==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----'
>>> publicKey.exportKey()
'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMI....==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY----'
```

or in PKCS#8 format:

```
>>> privateKey.exportKey(pkcs=8)
'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMI....==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY----'
>>> publicKey.exportKey(pkcs=8)
'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMI....==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY----'
```

References:

- [`Crypto.PublicKey.RSA#construct`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#construct)
- [`Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj#exportKey`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey)

Comment: Simple and works perfectly. Thank you. I just noticed they detailed how to do that on the page directly previous to the one I was looking at.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Is it maybe possible to include the CRT parameters during the call to `construct`? Could you remove your comment & close vote if you think this question is OK?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, it's possible to include some CRT parameters, but it's kind of strange, considering that $p$, $q$ and $p^{-1} \bmod{q}$ are the additional parameters and not the traditional dp, dq and q_inv.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. I guess it's not hard to calculate the required parameters (something you can actually do with just the `e`, `d` and `n` values to my surprise - that'll take some CPU time though)